# Variable inside a curl Array

Tags: linux, bash, curl, jq

How to put the variable "user" in this array. The way it is not it doesn't work sadly. The $user variable should be john.smith for example.

I have the following output:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXX" --request POST --data '["$user@test.com"]' "https://mattermost.test.com/api/v4/teams/$team/invite/email"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of single quotes (`'`) in the `--data` field.  This prevents the shell from expanding variables.

Compare `echo '$user'` to `echo "$user"` and you'll see the problem.

There's a number of ways to handle this, but one way is to close/open the `'` around the variable.

e.g.

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXX" --request POST --data '["'$user'@test.com"]' "https://mattermost.test.com/api/v4/teams/$team/invite/email"
```

The reason you don't see this with your Bearer token is because you're using `"`, which allows the variable to be expanded.